# Why a part of my mesh disappears and its untexturable?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, topology

I'm still learning Blender and i'm trying to create something on my own, without tutorial. I created my whole mesh using "Mirror" modifier (I didn't apply it), but when I started texture painting, I realized that a part of my mesh is untexturable. I added a procedural texture to the object and it worked fine. I tried to fix the UV map by adding seams to edges, but it didnt help. I realized that topology of my object is not so good and that could be reason of my problem, so I tried to fix it with Instant Meshes, because im not really good at modeling and I don't know how to do it manualy. When I uploaded my object, I saw that untexturable part of my mesh disappeared. I don't know what to do with something like this and what to do next time to not make mistakes like this, so maybe someone will know.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played about with a much more basic mesh, mirrored in X & Y like yours, and it looks to me like the rest of the mesh doesn't actually 'exist' for UV mapping etc. until you've applied the modifier.
Safest bet is to duplicate the object (select then hit Shift+D in 'object' mode) and then apply the mirror mod on the new object, unwrap & texture that.
Then if you want to change the model, edit the original mirror-modified object, and duplicate & apply the mirror modifier again.

Here's my  test- [image: Mirrored mesh in Edit mode]

So the only geometry that truly 'exists' is the bit that turns orange in Edit mode, until you apply the mirror modifier, all you'll get is the same UV'd texture mirrored.
If you unwrap your model before applying the modifier, you should only see the 'real' geometry in the UV editor, so that's all the UV'd image or whatever will be applied to (the rest of the model will get the same texture but mirrored the same as the geometry).
Like this- [image: TrueGeometryUVs]
As you can see there's only the 'real' quater of the mirrored object in the UVs when unwrapped.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have tried to apply the modifier, but some parts are still unable to texture.When I added "Solidify" modifier some of parts become visible in Instant Meshes, but not all of them. When I'm painting on object with "Mirror" modifier applied, it looks like on the image and im not able to paint the center. I tried to unwrap it with and without seams, I tried to use Smart UV Project. I was able to see the orange selection of broken part on the UV map, but texturing still don't works. Image: [link](http://prntscr.com/sbcztb)

Comment: Maybe uplod the .blend so I can have a look. Also: have you checked you normals in 'edit' mode- make sure they are all pointing 'out'? if you can't paint on something in texture paint it's usually a flipped normals issue whenever I've had that problem.
When you are in 'edit' mode the 'overlays' drop-down in Blender 2.8x has 'normals' down the bottom, to show them in the viewport.

Comment: Yup, I just fliped normals and now it works fine, thanks!

Comment: Kewl!... Bung me a vote for the answer then please...